# Best OpenId API for ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, openid

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC application and I want to use OpenId.

What is the best option?

- DotNetOpenId
- RPX
- Other???

Does anyone know what StackOverflow uses? Is the Login UI custom-developed, or provided by an API/service?

Comment: This question is a bit old now, relative to the pace of innovation in this area.  SO doesn't favour duplicate questions, otherwise I'd re-ask this one, looking for a contemporary set of answers.

Comment: So is DotNetOpenId still the #1 option.?

Comment: I guess it's called DotNetOpenAuth now

Answer (score 49, accepted):

We use the excellent DotNetOpenId library here on Stack Overflow:

> http://code.google.com/p/dotnetopenid/

now moved to:

> http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/

Our *original* login UI was provided by [ID Selector](http://www.idselector.com/), but we've since rolled our own minimalist version.

Comment: Well, looks like we need to upgrade our ID Selector to RPX!

Comment: Yes looks like it. Let us know how it goes.

Comment: -1 on RPXNow.  
http://blog.nerdbank.net/2009/01/why-using-rpxnow-is-bad-idea.html

Comment: I'm actually about to migrate from RPX back to openid-selector. The RPX servers are down about 5% of the time that someone tries to register.

Comment: Would you modify your answer, nearly a year on?  Does this information still hold true today?

Answer (score 17):

I'll second the recommendation for DotNetOpenId and add a recommendation for [openid-selector](http://code.google.com/p/openid-selector/) (open source version of idselector)

Comment: Thanks! Just tried it, Exellent compaird to the idselector.com's. Specially if you do need to change the look or language :P

Comment: Because it was the first. I believe there are better alternatives now, but I don't know what they are. I use RPXnow whenever possible.

Comment: Here is an example how to do it: http://weblogs.asp.net/haithamkhedre/archive/2011/03/13/openid-authentication-with-asp-net-mvc3-dotnetopenauth-and-openid-selector.aspx