# how to start using openID in an asp.net mvc3 project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, dotnetopenauth

I want to have authentication mechanism for my site (in asp.net mvc3), first option openID another option via my site. I don't know how to start with dotnetopenid, because it does not have a good document or some guidance to start with it. Is there any visual document or any useful step by step resource for it. The other question: I want to have google and yahoo openID authentication, is there any difference for using both of them?!

tanks a lot for your suggestions

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could do worse than download the [ASP.NET MVC 2 OpenID web site (C#)](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/81153747-70d7-477b-b85a-0374e7edabef) template from the Visual Studio Gallery.

> A C# ASP.NET MVC project template to
>   get you on a strong start on a web
>   site that accepts OpenID.  An OAuth
>   service provider is also included so
>   that clients can access user data with
>   user authorization and without a
>   password.

There is also a templated called [Html5-MVC3-BP-OpenAuth](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/fe61654a-e420-4012-affb-04a0607fb10b) which is described as:

> This template creates an MVC3 Razor
>   project with Html5 Boilerplate from
>   Paul Irish.  Also includes the
>   DotNetOpenAuth CTP for authentication
>   via OpenId, Twitter (OAuth) or
>   Facebook (OAuth2).

Alternately check out [MvcOpenID - An OpenID Starter Kit for ASP.NET MVC](http://mvcopenid.codeplex.com/) on Codeplex:

> "MvcOpenID is an OpenID starter kit
>   for ASP.NET MVC. It is first and
>   foremost a learning tool. I've learned
>   a lot about OpenID while developing
>   this and commented the code a lot.
>   Running the application and stepping
>   through the code is the best and
>   probably the fastest way to learn.
>   Apart from it's educational value you
>   can also use it as a starter kit for
>   your ASP.NET MVC based web
>   applications."

Answer (score 1):

It was a few years ago, but I integrated DotNetOpenId in my blog:

http://blog.dantup.com/2009/04/using-openid-in-your-aspnet-mvc.html

It was pretty painless, and all the required code is on that page. It seems that StackOverflow also uses the same library:

[Best OpenId API for ASP.NET MVC application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526890/best-openid-api-for-asp-net-mvc-application/526897#526897)

Comment: I like your simple to the point code samples, without all the surrounding bloat.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally you might want to checks Dominick Baier blog posts [here](http://www.leastprivilege.com/AccessControlServiceV2RegisteringWebIdentitiesInYourApplicationsConcepts.aspx) and [here](http://www.leastprivilege.com/AccessControlServiceV2RegisteringWebIdentitiesInYourApplicationsCode.aspx) on the subject.